# Custom Listview with imageview

Tags: android, imageview

I got image download code from, 
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html
what puzzled me is how he got the imageview's view back from the download() without return value
from ImageDownloader?

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
...
 public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = new ImageView(parent.getContext());
            view.setPadding(6, 6, 6, 6);
        }

        imageDownloader.download(URLS[position], (ImageView) view);

        return view;
    }
..


public class ImageDownloader {
  ...
   private void forceDownload(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    ....
     case CORRECT:
                    task = new BitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);
                    DownloadedDrawable downloadedDrawable = new DownloadedDrawable(task);
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(downloadedDrawable);
                    imageView.setMinimumHeight(156);
                    task.execute(url);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look inside `BitmapDownloadTask` class, there is `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`
 on `OnPostExecute` method which sets bitmap once it is downloaded.

Note that `OnPostExecute` method is called once the image is downloaded.

EDIT:
When you are calling download, you are passing reference of `ImageView` object as a parameter. So when that method is making changes such as setting image, it is doing same to the object that is passed.

Objects are passed as reference in java. So both `ImageView` are referencing to the same object.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I understand the setImageBitmap and the trigger of OnPostExexcute.  How the imageView is return to the calling function.
Could it be the view is passed as reference?

Answer (score 0):

I did some search on java.

[Pass by reference in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411902/pass-by-reference-in-java)

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/passing.html

It looks like imageview is passed in as object, hence, it passed in as reference.
Thanks for helping.